# Overriding Enum._generate_next_value_ not working as expected with MRO?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums, multiple-inheritance

Why does overriding `_generate_next_value_` only work if done in the LAST inherited enum?

For example:

```
class AutoEnum(Enum):
    def _generate_next_value_(name, start, count, last_values):
        return 'overriding _generate_next_value'

class OtherEnum(Enum):
    def some_other_method(self):
        return

class AutoOther(AutoEnum, OtherEnum):
    TEST = auto()

class OtherAuto(OtherEnum, AutoEnum):
    TEST = auto()


print(f'{AutoOther.TEST}: mro={getmro(AutoOther)}\n'
      f'name: {AutoOther.TEST.name}, value: {AutoOther.TEST.value}')

print(f'{OtherAuto.TEST}: mro={getmro(OtherAuto)}\n'
      f'name: {OtherAuto.TEST.name}, value: {OtherAuto.TEST.value}')
```

Output:

```
AutoOther.TEST: mro=(<enum 'AutoOther'>, <enum 'AutoEnum'>, <enum 'OtherEnum'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>)
name: TEST, value: 1

OtherAuto.TEST: mro=(<enum 'OtherAuto'>, <enum 'OtherEnum'>, <enum 'AutoEnum'>, <enum 'Enum'>, <class 'object'>)
name: TEST, value: overriding _generate_next_value
```

If somehow the default `_generate_next_value_` is being set every time if it's not specifically overridden, how is it not being reset again when Enum is inherited?

I think I'm missing something with how/why this is working like this.

Comment: override it in auto other?

Comment: I'm not asking how to change the functionality here, if that wasn't clear. I'm asking why the behaviour is like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Special methods such as `_generate_next_value_` need to be in place before the class is actually created.  In order to support this, `EnumMeta` looks for these special methods in the base `Enum` class -- and the base `Enum` class is the last one listed.

It certainly feels like any other `Enum` classes should also be searched for the enum methods, though.

[Issue created](https://bugs.python.org/issue42678).

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.