# Enum with custom base class, __new__ and auto()

Tags: python, enums

I have an `Enum` base class that turns string values into lowercase and defaults to the lowercase name for `auto` values:

```
from enum import Enum, auto

class LowercaseEnum(str, Enum):
    def __new__(cls, value):
        """
        Passthrough defined so child classes can have custom __new__.
        """
        v = value.lower() if isinstance(value, str) else value
        self = str.__new__(cls, v)
        self._value_ = v
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def _generate_next_value_(name, *args):
        """
        Handle auto() values by lowercasing the enum name.
        """
        return name.lower()
```

I added `__new__` mostly because of [Override __new__ of a class which extends Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76124622/2988730).

When I extend `LowercaseEnum` with something simple, it appears that I can use `auto()` normally:

```
class Test(LowercaseEnum):
    ABC = auto()
    DEF = auto()
    GHI = 'GHI'
```

```
>>> list(Test)
[<Test.ABC: 'abc'>, <Test.DEF: 'def'>, <Test.GHI: 'ghi'>]
```

But when I try to extend `LowercaseEnum` with a custom `__new__`, `auto()` appears to break:

```
class Test2(LowercaseEnum):
    def __new__(cls, value, index):
        self = super().__new_member__(cls, value)
        self.index = index
        return self
    ABC = auto(), 0
    DEF = auto(), 1
    GHI = 'GHI', 2
```

```
>>> list(Test2)
[<Test2.ABC: <enum.auto object at 0x7f662173dcd0>>,
 <Test2.DEF: <enum.auto object at 0x7f662173de50>>,
 <Test2.GHI: 'ghi'>]
```

Adding an explicit `self._value_ = value` in `Test2.__init__` does not appear to make any difference.

[Overriding Enum._generate_next_value_ not working as expected with MRO?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65362203/2988730) gave me the idea to try an explicit `_generate_next_value_` to `Test2`, which did nothing either:

```
@staticmethod
def _generate_next_value_(name, *args):
    return super()._generate_next_value_(name, *args)
```

For what it's worth, `index` appears to be working OK:

```
>>> [x.index for x in Test2]
[0, 1, 2]
```

I want to see something that looks the same as it did for `Test`. What am I missing in my enum class?

---

I am using Python 3.8. It appears that this issue has been fixed by 3.11, but I don't have access to the newer interpreter at this time.

Comment: I have no issue with Python 3.11.3!

Comment: @javadr. I'm using 3.8. That being said, I edited that info into the question. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: It seems you've corrected the output in your new revision of the question! I mean `<Test2.GHI: 'ghi'>`

Comment: @javadr. The non-auto stuff works fine. I want `<Test2.ABC: <enum.auto object at 0x7f662173dcd0>>` to be <Test2.ABC: 'abc'>. I'm not sure where the plumbing for `_generate_next_value_` breaks

Comment: OK. BTW, as I mentioned I got the following in Python 3.11.3:

```list(Test2) ===>>>
[<Test2.ABC: 'abc'>, <Test2.DEF: 'def'>, <Test2.GHI: 'ghi'>]```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens when you create an auto() element is in the __setitem__ method of the _EnumDict class, as so:

```
if isinstance(value, auto):
    if value.value == _auto_null:
        value.value = self._generate_next_value(
                key,
                1,
                len(self._member_names),
                self._last_values[:],
                )
        self._auto_called = True
    value = value.value
```

But your value is equal to (<auto object>, 0), so it's not an instance of the auto class and therefore not replaced by the correct value.

What you can do, even if it's more complicated is creating a new Meta like this:

```
class NewEnumMeta(EnumMeta):
    def __new__(mcs, cls, bases, classdict, **kwargs):
        for i, member in enumerate(classdict._member_names):
            value = classdict._last_values[i]
            if type(value) is tuple and len(value) >= 2 and isinstance(value[0], auto):
                dict.__setitem__(classdict, member, (classdict._generate_next_value(member), *value[1:]))
        return EnumMeta.__new__(mcs, cls, bases, classdict, **kwargs)
```

and then just change:
`class Test2(LowercaseEnum, metaclass=NewEnumMeta):`

Comment: That actually makes a lot of sense. I'll wait a bit, but can't imagine there will be an easier way to do it

Comment: Is there any reason not to set the metaclass directly on LowercaseEnum?

Comment: FWIW, it worked perfectly on the base enum

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes because the tuple implementation of the enum is only defined on the Test2 class, the LowercaseEnum enum seems to be also used for regular elements (Test 1)

Comment: But you could, for me it just made less sens